# Passing value to Constructor by using new Statement

Tags: java, object, new-operator

```
public class MultipleObjects {
    int a;
    int b;

    MultipleObjects(int a,int b) {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }

    MultipleObjects(MultipleObjects g) {
        a=g.a;
        b=g.b;
    }

    static MultipleObjects display(/*MultipleObjects o1,MultipleObjects o2*/) {
        MultipleObjects temp = new MultipleObjects(new MultipleObjects(2,3));
        return temp;
    }
}
```

I used 2 new statements one within the other here.What ıs thing in the brackets of outer new statement? value or object.If object,how? Can someone explain it detailedly?

Comment: You create an instance of `MultipleObjects` using the `(int, int)` constructor, then pass it to the copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you created a new MultipleObjects using constructor that takes `int, int` as params then you invoke another constructor(AKA copy constructor) passing it the newly created object.
Your code

```
MultipleObjects temp = new MultipleObjects(new MultipleObjects(2,3));
```

Is equivalent to

```
MultipleObjects foo = new MultipleObjects(2,3);
MultipleObjects temp = new MultipleObjects(foo);
```

Comment: thanks for the example.Your example explains what ı wanted to understand exactly.

Comment: @FurkanAktaş you can always upvote if you find the answer useful :)